# Move a location of a character in a string

Tags: c#

I would like to add the X between () based on user the problem is that i cannot know in advance the length of the string because it's dynamically changing becuase of some HTML tags are added

The string has the following structure

> Text .... AAA (X) BBB () CCC () DDD () .... Text

HTML tags can be available

To make my question more simple,
question is: find the last () or (X) which is as close as possible to DDD .
example

> Text ... AAA() BBB () CCC () DDD  >span style="color=red">  (X) >/span> ....text

How can without destroying the structure of the text file change the location of the X

I tried almost all string functions replace, remove, substring ... etc the problem in case of the (x) at the end and if there is (x) somewhere else in the file, how can i find out the position of the last () with or without X

EDIT:

possible Input can be:

```
<p>
     <span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";color:black'>AAA() - BBB() - CCC() - DDD</span><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";color:red'>(X)</span></b>
     <span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";color:black'>
        <o:p></o:p>
     </span>
  </p>
```

No output i just want to know the location of the last () which in this case the position of () which contains x (X) after red'>

Comment: Not quite clear, can you please post the input and output separately?

Comment: Maybe replace `()` with `(X)`? :/

Comment: What is your question, replacing `()` with `(X)` or `find out the position of the last () with or without X`?

Comment: @Reniuz: Seems there are multiple `()` or `(X)` and OP after the last one?

Comment: [String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you should have tried gives you last position... Since it presumably did not work please clarify other restrictions.

Comment: Perhaps a better way might be to create a `class` that you can "select" what tags to use and what item to select, and then build a custom `ToString` to generate the actual string?

Comment: You want to change the position of X without altering the original. Very odd request.

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, i would like to find the position of the last () with or without X

Comment: I really don't understand why getting negative comments, maybe i'm not clear because i'm not native english but i'm just posting a problem. any way, thanks

Comment: @Maro: Negative comments are probably because you haven't show [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). English is not the case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i would like to find the position of the last () with or without X

Find the position of the last `()` and the position of the last `(X)`, then find which one is larger.

```
string input = "Text .... AAA (X) BBB () CCC () DDD () .... Text";

int withXPos = input.LastIndexOf("(X)");
int withoutXPos = input.LastIndexOf("()");

int lastPos = Math.Max(withoutXPos, withXPos);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gunr2171 i wish it was that easy, () or (X) can also be found in the text later in the document, therefore it should be somehow linked to the DDD any way, thanks for you effots +1 from me

Comment: If there are more restrictions you need to post them.

Comment: no more restriction (find the last () or (X) which is after the DDD

Comment: @Maro: So what you expect in case of `Text .... AAA (X) BBB () CCC () DDD` ? when no `()` or `(X)` are after the DDD

Comment: there is always () or (X) after DDD but maybe there are some HTML tags between, the solution you provided is perfect but imagine the following text " Text .... AAA (X) BBB () CCC () DDD (X) text text ()
in this case i'm interested in the one only near DDD not the one after text

Comment: but as i said between DDD and () or (X) there can be some html code

Answer (score 1):

using  [String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var test=@"<p><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:'Tahoma','sans-serif';color:black'>AAA() - BBB() - CCC() - DDD</span><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:'Tahoma','sans-serif';color:red'>(X)</span></b>
                     <span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:'Tahoma','sans-serif';color:black'><o:p></o:p></span></p>";

 var withx = test.LastIndexOf("(X)");
 var without = test.LastIndexOf("()");
```

Comment: Thnkx humpty dumpty as i wrote bellow, i hope it was so simple
() or (X) can also be found in the text later in the document, therefore it should be somehow linked to the DDD any way, thanks for you effots +1 from me

Comment: @Maro: No problem, next time when you ask question try to put some code that you tried to avoid down-votes !!